# How to order by select result according to my custom format in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

The student table has a column called courseid. And the course table has two columns called courseid and coursename.

Now I want to select the students where select course name is  **math or music, or physical** and return the result that must order by course **physical or music or physical**. If  I want to select the students where course name is **music or math or physical** and return the result that must order by class **music or math or physical**.

I trid to write the sql, but it seems that I could not use `order by` directly.

```
select * 
from student s 
  inner join course c 
          on t.courseid=s.courseid 
         and c.coursename in ('math','music','physical')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN c.coursename='music' THEN 3 WHEN c.coursenane='math' THEN 2 WHEN c.coursename='physical' THEN 1 END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * 
    from student s inner join course c on t.courseid=s.courseid
    where
     c.coursename in ('math','music','physical')
    order by
     c.coursename;
```

Comment: c.coursename is just a example,the name seems has not rule.It can be 'English,Fresh'.